# Which files contain DNS cache for Google Chrome?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, firefox, caching, dns

In Windows there are two DNS cache respositories: the operating system and the browser. Flushing the operating system DNS does not clear the browser DNS cache (running `ipconfig /flushdns` does not remove entries from Chrome DNS cache).

I understand you can clear and view the Google Chrome DNS cache by navigating to `chrome://net-internals/#dns` in the browser. Since this data is persistent (if you close the browser and re-open it, this data populates again), it means it's being written to disc. Which file contains this data?

**Use-Case**: I want to access remote client Chrome DNS cache to detect users running proxies or tunnels (SOCKS5 will use proxy dns, so a significant difference between the OS DNS cache and the browser cache will indicate proxy/tunnel usage).

As a bonus I'd also like to know where Firefox and Edge/IExplorer stores this data. It's not as easy to view because Firefox doesn't have the convenient net-internals.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be

```
C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Cache\data_3
```

dns cache is definitely in there, might be some other data as well - so be careful

Answer (score -1):

The cache data  files in windows are saved under

```
   AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Profile 1\Cache
```

all data is stored in this folder. 
what ever you're looking for should be here

Comment: There is no match for any DNS entries in any of those cache files. Is there any encoding used? `strings * | grep randomdomain.com` returns nothing. Assume randomdomain.com should be in my DNS cache (it's not the real name).